# codeigniter connectivity with mssql using sqlsrv driver in wamp server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter, wamp

I am not able to connect the mssql with codeigniter in wamp server

I am getting the following error

A Database Error Occurred
Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:\wamp\www\secure.leaftrack.com\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 124

Comment: Open a window on the server and try connecting to the database server manually.  You should get a more informative error message.

Answer (score 0):

After a few day of problems my company was able to solve this.

We were using the dll for mssql from PHP version 5.2.11.  Once we updated to 5.2.17 it was fixed!